# Search for specific load of file

Tags: file

Somewhere on my website the following file is loaded: `data:application/font-woff;base64....`

I want to remove this file, but I can not find out in what specific file it is loaded.

Is there an easy way to find this out in Magento?

Comment: it may be font file which is creating by your theme refer http://sosweetcreative.com/2613/font-face-and-base64-data-uri

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. use linux [find](https://linux.die.net/man/1/find) command. login to your server via ssh then do:

   ```
   cd /path/to/magento/root
   find js app skin lib -type f -exec grep -iHn --color=always 'data:application/font-woff;base64' {} \;
   ```
2. if that doesn't help try searching for various string combinations`'application.*base'` or `'data.*base64'`
3. if #1 and #2 doesn't work dump your database to db.sql file and search it with grep:

   ```
   grep -iHn --color=always 'font-woff.*base64' db.sql
   ```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I tried that, but that does not give any result. What am I missing?

Comment: could be whitespaces try searching for various strings, use regex, for example 'application/font-woff' or 'data.*base64' or 'base64' or 'font-woff.*base'

Comment: try #2 and #3 from my updated answer. also i added js folder to search.

Comment: Thanks a lot! That works much better, but in that case I get to many results. The original file is offcourse much longer. Can I search for all files that starts with `data:application/font-woff;`? So that I get a better result.

Comment: find js app skin lib -type f -exec grep -iHn --color=always 'data:application/font-woff;' {} \;

Comment: Thanks, that's what I thought. But sadly that does not give any result. The file is loaded on all pages, but I can not find out where and how.

Comment: Found it, it was because of an external script. Thanks for your help! :)